# Facebook integration using standard GET request issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova

Everyone,

We have a Phonegap app that, for Facebook integration, opens a browser window, passes the Login URL (with all permissions request etc.) and waits for the location to be a `login_success.html#access_token=[Token]`

However, on some devices we get the correct token and on some devices we get `/login_success.html#\_=\_ response`.

NOTE: That varies from device to device and is not steady at all.

Is there any reason why that happens?
We have multiple devices both on iOS 5 and iOS 6 (5.1.1 and 6.1.2, 6.1.3) and some of them work just fine and some have this issue. We had tried an App removal and other things (but not the device reset) and we're getting a steady issue on some devices and not an issue on other.

Comment: Even, I would say, we're getting the first response without hash tag at all.

Comment: Can you tell us on which devices you are getting `#_=_ response`?

Comment: I got the login_success.html without #access_token=[Token] on iOS 5.1.1 simulator, on iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1.3 and on iPad with iOS 5.1.1. We don't have this issue on iPhone 4S with 6.1.2

Comment: Are you seeing two calls to your callback, or just one?

Answer (score 1):

for using facebook I do like this:

```
function facebookLogin() {
ref = window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOURID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token', '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event){ manageLoadstart(event)});}
```

And

```
function manageLoadstart(event) {
if (event.url.indexOf('https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#') !== -1) {
    var charIndex = event.url.indexOf('&');
    var firstExtraction = event.url.substring(charIndex);
    var newUrl = event.url.replace(firstExtraction, '');
    var startUrl = newUrl.substr(0, 65);
    var accessToken = newUrl.replace(startUrl, '');
    saveFacebookToken(accessToken);
    ref.close();
}}
```

I use this with phonegap 2.6.0. The loadstop event don't work. So it will go 3 times in manageloadstart, and check everytime the url.

Comment: The problem is (and I verified that with Fiddler) the /dialog/oauth?client_id is redirected to login and then from login it is redirected to the https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html without access_token in the end

Comment: I am using Phonegap 2.3.0 and am having theh same problem. In the end there is no token appended in a URL param with the success.html Facebook Url.